# Should I install OpenVPN on its own hard drive or partition?

Tags: partitioning, vpn, openvpn

I recently performed a clean install of Ubuntu 16.04 LTE. I now want to set up a private VPN Server using OpenVPN. I have a 1Tb internal drive and a 500Gb External drive. I want to use my PC as my primary computer. I've done some research and understand that using a VPN Server as a pc poses no problem. I have found a good tutorial in installing OpenVPN on a Ubuntu 16.04 LTE o/s. However, I can't find any reference to where I should install it. Do I install it in its own partition on my main drive or on the external drive. Will installing on the external drive (or for that matter, my internal drive) slow the system down. I.e. Are download speeds choked (affecting Netflix streaming video for example). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In general for any software it doesn't matter where you install. Programs can be executed by OS from anywhere, from where it can read the executable. But as you said it could be little bit slower if its on external partition while startup and if its saving media to external drive then it can perform slow.

To answer just exact your question, i think you have got good space on your primary hard disk. So go ahead and install it anywhere on your primary hard disk. Or if you using any automated install script from OpenVPN then let it do what it does. It will probably install at right place.

If you still face problem then please share the details/source about installer, then i can help you more.

Cheers !!

Comment: This is correct, your HD will have little to do with VPN performance, unless you have a very, very slow hard drive.